# What must I do to save this kalanchoe?

Tags: succulents, kalanchoe, recovery

The leaves of this kalanchoe are thin and greyish. I noticed that the main stem looks like the trunk of a tree. 
When I received it as a gift, it was beautiful, very small and filled with flowers. But then it was thrown off of its pot many times by a toddler. I planted it in a bigger pot and it grew new leaves, but it doesn't look well at all.[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing it needs fertilizer. Woody stems are said to be a sign of potassium deficiency. If the leaves are dull, it probably also needs more nitrogen. If the leaves are purple, it probably needs phosphorus.

New potting soil doesn't always come with many nutrients.